# How to check the Nuxt.js version of an application?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Let's say I just joined a new team. How can I quickly check the version of Nuxt the application is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I just had to open the `package.json` file and check the version for the `@nuxt/core` package.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply via command line in the directory where your package.json is located:

yarn: `yarn list | grep @nuxt/core`

npm: `npm ls | grep @nuxt/core`

If you run `npx nuxt dev` or `yarn nuxt dev` it also shows the current version.